# Nokia 3 here getZoom after setViewBound

Tags: here-api

I've got problem with getting zoom level of the here map.

I need to read zoom level after adding some new markers to map group.

```
var zoom1 = map.getZoom(); // 13

var groupTmp = new H.map.Group();

vehicle.each(function()
{
    var coords = {lat: parseFloat($(this).attr('latitude')), lng: parseFloat($(this).attr('longitude'))};

    groupTmp.addObject(new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: ''}));
});

map.setViewBounds(groupTmp.getBounds());

var zoom2 = map.getZoom(); // 13
```

As you can see, var zoom1 and zoom2 no differs.

When I check zoom level from the console by typing "map.getZoom()" after a sec or by using setInterval, it shows correct zoom.

Answer (score 0):

check the zoom after the view change has ended by adding a listener.

```
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend',handler );
var handler=function(evt) {
        var zoom2 = map.getZoom();
};
```